# Unable to add a user with "Basic" Access Level to Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

After many attempts to add the new user using the UI in the Azure DevOps portal, I keep getting errors. Perhaps there is a bug in the web portal's UI. How do I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Azure CLI and the Azure DevOps CLI extensions to solve the problem.

1. Log in with the Azure CLI

```
az login
```

2. Install the Azure DevOps CLI extension

```
az extension add --name "azure-devops"
```

3. Add the user through the CLI.

```
az devops user add --email-id "user-email@example.com" --license-type express
```

4. Navigate to the portal and confirm the user Access Level is "Basic".